# Best way to print fixed columns table in Perl (using underscores instead of spaces)

Tags: perl, format

I need to format database records into a table that a web forum can display properly (using bbcode). The forum in question does not respect spaces no matter which type of formatting tag I use but does have a monospace font, so I need to replace all spaces by underscores like this to keep everything aligned:

```
Field____Field____Field
Value____Value____Value
Value____Value____Value
Value____Value____Value
Value____Value____Value
```

I've looked into Perl formats and printf, but I can't figure out how to make the spaces and tabs into underscore using these methods. The text also have variable length, so I need the columns to be variable as well (can't hardcode fixed values).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Would not the bbcode tag `[code]` preserve spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a hack but I would use sprintf but I would replace the space in my values with another character that can not be found in these values (like ~). This can be done with a simple regex. 
After sprintf I would replace the spaces with underlines and my special character in the values back to space.

Comment: Just realized I was looking for sprintf (and not printf)... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything advanced, you just need to replace the spaces with underscore:

```
my $str = "Field     Field     Field";
$str =~ tr/ /_/;
print $str;
```

Comment: The replace part is easy if you already have the string generated, but I don't. The info is in the db, and I need to print multiple rows with minimal width for each columns (with around 2 spaces as gutters between columns). Printf is the more direct approach to format dynamic-width columns, but it uses spaces, and I don't know how to put the output of printf in a variable.

Comment: Just realized I can use sprintf (and not printf)... I was looking at the wrong thing!

Answer (score 0):

In case the values in your fields may contain tabs (or other space-like characters) you may want to do the following:

```
my $str = "Field     Field\tContinued     Field";
$str =~ s/\s/_/g;
print $str;
```